# angular.js:533 TypeError: Cannot read property 'modules' of undefined at Object.$state.loadModules Magento 2.3.4 p2

Tags: installation, frontend-error, console, magento2.3.4-p2

> I am facing below an error in browser console log while installing magento 2.3.4 p2 version
> in localhost. PHP version is 7.1.10. Please check below error and attached screenshot below.

```
angular.js:533 TypeError: Cannot read property 'modules' of undefined
        at Object.$state.loadModules (customize-your-store.js:79)
        at m.$scope.checkModuleConstraints (customize-your-store.js:46)
        at fn (eval at compile (angular.js:19141), <anonymous>:4:186)
        at e (angular.js:19141)
        at m.$eval (angular.js:8794)
        at m.$apply (angular.js:8811)
        at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (angular.js:19141)
        at jg (angular.js:4598)
        at HTMLButtonElement.d (angular.js:4512)
```

[image]

> If any idea, please guide me. Thanks in Advance !!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I resolved this error by removing `Security malware softwares` from my
> browser and just reload browser by controls `Ctrls Shift R`.
>
> And second thing is `angular.js` stores data in browser local storage
> while installations process, and if it is not stores it then this
> issue might be occured.